# Get child's child record in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities (I18N is a localized entity):

```
public class Post { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Boolean IsPublished { get; set; }
  public Category Category { get; set; }
  public List<PostI18N> PostsI18N { get; set; }
}

public class Category { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public List<CategoryI18N> CategoriesI18N { get; set; }
}

public class PostI18N { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public String Text { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryI18N { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public String Slug { get; set; }    
}
```

I need to get a list of posts with its categories all localized so I have:

```
var posts = await _context
   .Posts
   .SelectMany(x => x.PostsI18N, 
     (Post, PostI18N) => new { Post, PostI18N, Post.Category })
   .Where(x => x.PostI18N.LanguageCode == "en")
   .Select(x => new PostDTO {
      Id = x.Post.Id,
      Title = x.PostI18N.Title,
      Text = x.PostI18N.Text,
      CategoryDto = new CategoryDto {
        Id = x.Category.Id,
        Name = // ??
        Slug = // ??
        // The name and slug should be taken from
        // x.Post.Category.CategoriesI18N which has LanguageCode = "en"
      }         
   });
```

My problem is how to get the Category localized info (see comment in query).

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: As I see in the model, there is a one-to-many relationship between Category and CategoryI18N entities! Because of that you have to write a sub-query  or another query for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
Name = x.Post.Category.CategoriesI18N.Any(c => c.LanguageCode == "en") 
       ? x.Post.Category.CategoriesI18N.First(c => c.LanguageCode == "en").Name
       : string.Empty // or whatever default you want when a match is not found
```

Or it might make more sense to do

```
CategoryDto =  x.Post.Category.CategoriesI18N
                .Where(c => c.LanguageCode == "en")
                .Select(c => new CategoryDto {
                     Id = x.Category.Id,
                     Name = c.Name,
                     Slug = c.Slug
                 }).FirstOrDefault()
```

if all the values should come from the same `CategoryI18N`

If you still want a `CategoryDto` if there are no matches you can just add a `?? new CategoryDto { ... }` after `FirstOrDefault()`.